# Вывод hello world в консоль asm

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

Есть асмовая программа, которая выводит Hello World!:

```
CSEG segment  
org 100h
start:
    mov ah, 9
    mov dx, offset messg
    int 21h

    mov ax, 0
    int 16h

    int 20h  
    messg db 'Hello, world!$'
    CSEG ends
end start
```

Пользуюсь досбоксом, компилирую тасмом.
Компилируется все без ошибок, но после выполнения в консоль вылетает всякая белиберда и досбокс вешается намертво. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас код написан для компиляции в com файл (org 100h только для .com нужно), а вы собираете exe. Для exe файлов используется более сложное оформление кода с указанием сегментов. например как тут https://habr.com/ru/post/326078/

Comment: @Mike, хорошо, а как тогда его собрать как .com?

Comment: Как то уже забыл как это собиралось 20 лет назад ... (.com файлы уже 20 лет как не используются) В общем гугл говорит что exe превращают в com с помощью утилиты exe2bin. теоретически еще у линкера могут быть какие то ключи, надо смотреть документацию на ваш линкер

Comment: Еще посмотрите может вместе с tasm у вас есть его линкер `tlink` он вроде собирает по `tlink /t test.obj`

Comment: @Mike, все верно. С моим паком для 8086 не было линкера tlink. Теперь все работает так как должно. Спасибо!